# Return multiple objects using Json.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, json.net

With the built-in json converter I return multiple objects in my action like this:

```
return Json(new { success = true, data = units });
```

When I use the JSON.NET library how can I do the same?

This does obviously not compile:

```
return new { success = true, data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(units) };
```

I do not want to create an extra viewmodel for this containing both properties.

Do I have a wrong understanding of the default Json javascript serializer maybe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Newtonsoft.Json to serialise your objects, you can create a new ActionResult class and pass the data in the result.

For example:

```
public class NewtonsoftJsonResult : ContentResult
{
    private readonly object _data;

    public NewtonsoftJsonResult(object data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_data);
        ContentType = "application/json";

        base.ExecuteResult(context);
    }
}
```

Just return your custom ActionResult with the anonymous object as data:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return new NewtonsoftJsonResult(new { success = true, data = units});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(units)` will result in a string returned to JavaScript. JavaScript won't see `data` as containing some "real" data but rather a simple string, with curly parentheses inside.

Use your first sentence as usual. MVC's `Json` method will serialize the objects within.

For example:

```
class Units
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
Units u = new Units { Width = 34, Height = 20 };

return Json(new { success = true, data = units });
```

will result in a Json that looks similar to this:

```
{ "success" : "true", "data" : { "Height" : "20", "Width" : "34" } } }
```

Comment: I do not want to use the built-in json serializer. My question is about Json.net and by the way in javascript I do this:  var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data); thus returning a json string is fine.